# Insert uploaded image to summernote editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg, summernote

My objective is to insert the uploaded image(local file) to the summernote editor.

Image uploading successfully, only need to insert into the editor.

I was trying to console log the editor instance, but it's showing undefined. If I can pass the editor instance to the `sendFile` function, I think the issue will be resolved.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/weodsagb/9/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.summernote').summernote({
    callbacks: {
     onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
      var url= sendFile(files[0], editor, welEditable);
    }
  },
  height: 300,
  focus: true,

});

  function sendFile(file, editor, welEditable) {
    data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);
    console.log(editor);
    /* $.ajax({
      data: data,
      type: "POST",
      url: "Test/test",
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(url) {
        editor.insertImage(welEditable, url);
        console.log(url); //eg:https://server-url/assets/images/a8f15ed.jpg
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, stat, err){
        console.log(stat+':'+err);
      }
    }); */
  }
});
```

```html
<head> 
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-bs4.js"></script>
</head>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="summernote"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On ajax success, we can insert the image to the editor instance by this way

```
success: function(url) {
  $('#summernote').summernote("insertImage", url, 'filename');
},
```

Don't need to insert into the `editor` from  `sendFile(file, editor, welEditable)` function param. For my case this solves the porblem.

Helpful [comment](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1173#issuecomment-115730874)

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting `'text/html' mode`

**Note:** There is no `editor`, `welEditable` params in [`onImageUpload`](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#onimageupload) callback

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.summernote').summernote({
    height: 300,
    focus: true,
    codemirror: {
      mode: 'text/html',
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-bs4.js"></script>
</head>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="summernote"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
On ajax success you can insert an image by

```
// getting old html 
let html = $('.summernote').summernote('code'); 

// setting updated html with image url
$('.summernote').summernote('code', html + '<img src="' + url + '"/>');
```

Comment: I was following from [here](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/72#issuecomment-27676684)

Comment: @unreleased that is posted on `2013`. but you are using the latest version

Comment: Actually, I need to upload image via ajax request to a specific folder and attach the image URL  to the editor. Converting the image to base64 and attach to the editor won't solve the problem. It would be helpful for me if you can save the image via ajax request.@Aswin Kumar

Comment: Thanks, @Aswin Kumar for your support. +1 for your time. I've solved the issue in a bit different way :)